# Ansible Documentation Parameters Chart: What are the Indented Rows?

Tags: ansible, syntax, documentation

I'm learning Ansible and don't understand something in the online documentation:

When I look up the doc on the [arista.eos.eos_command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/arista/eos/eos_command_module.html), I see this in the Parameters chart:

[image]

I understand that `commands` is a parameter for this module, for example:

```
  tasks:
  - name: Run "show verison"
    arista.eos.eos_command:
      commands: show version
```

Here, "***show version***" is a string command that I'm submitting to the remote device.  But in the above chart, what are those `answer` and `check_all` rows that are indented under `commands`?  What are they called?  Can I see an example of how to use them?  There doesn't seem to be a Guide to Ansible Documentation explaining what those suboptions are.  Very frustrating.

Thank you.

Comment: `commands` can be a list of dictionaries. Those dictionaries could then have those parameters. Just look at the example in the documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/arista/eos/eos_command_module.html#examples. E.g.: the fifth example.

Comment: That is actually explained in the print screen you took: _Commands may be represented either as simple strings **or as dictionaries as described below.**_

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you!  What are those indented rows called?  Would they be considered arguments to the parameter?  i.e., `answer` might be a list of strings that you would supply your initial command?  Despite the examples, I don't see how the subrows are used.  Thank you

Comment: Please make sure you understand what a list and a dict are. See for example [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). Rephrasing again the documentation and Benoit's comments, the `commands` parameter is a list. Each element in the list is either a simple string (i.e. a command to run) or a more complicated object described inside a dict. the "indented rows in the parameters chart" describe the keys inside each dict element if you use that format, as shown in the examples.

Comment: @Zeitounator Ahhhhhhhhhhh that makes a lot of sense, thank you.  If you write that up, I'll credit you with the question solution, as that was the explanation I was looking for!